# How to query work items by build or release in Azure DevOps Boards?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Azure DevOps allows to link work items with commits, build and releases. It works, and I can see all those links in a work item form. But is there a way to query work items using those links? I.e. query WIs associated with any or particular commit(s)/build(s)/release(s).

All I could find so far is to query WIs by count of external links and view a simple list of associated WIs from a particular build.

Answer (score 1):

You can not query work items using Artifact Links in UI. But you can use [Artifact Uri Query - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/artifact%20uri%20query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API to query work items linked to a given list of artifact URI. For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/artifacturiquery?api-version=5.1-preview.1

{
  "artifactUris": [
    "vstfs:///Build/Build/1566"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cece. Yes, I'm already digging in this direction. Hence a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238303/what-is-the-right-way-to-authenticate-azure-function-against-azure-devops-rest-a).
And still, I think this sort of query must be available in UI.

Comment: Yes, I've [submitted this suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/990276/query-work-items-by-build-or-release.html). And I marked your answer as useful (in my particular case), but I'm afraid it isn't really a solution for many DevOps users.