# What is the right way to authenticate Azure Function against Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

The goal is to develop an Azure function which should do some changes in Azure DevOps (like update work items, wiki pages etc), being triggered by Azure pipeline service hook.
Can I use function system identity in this case? And how can I give permissions for this identity to call DevOps REST APIs?

Comment: Hi Svetlana, have you ever found a proper solution for this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi, @Dimitris. Nope... Did not find any other way but to use PAT. Just used a special user account not related to any actual person.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but you can create [PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). Since you will use it for Azure Function I woudl recommend to use Azure KeyVault to store that token.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) you have the example how you can use it to fetch projects from Azure DevOps:

```
public static async void GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link) you have documentation for updating work items. I tested that with Postman, but I was able to edit work item using PAT.

Comment: Yes, that's all I could find as well. I hoped that there is a proper way, and I just can't get it due to vague MS documentation. And a proper way I'm sure is to use application system identity and RBAC, not PAT. 
I use System access token in Azure pipelines to access Azure DevOps via Powershell scripts and REST API. I think it must be done similarly with Azure Functions. The Function has system identity, so all is needed here - to provide access for this identity and a way to get access token for that identity.

Comment: Since you have this done for REST you can do actually the same from Azure Function right? Can you point me to any doc for this?

Comment: I have done it using REST, but in this case REST is called by a script on behalf of Azure DevOps pipeline and apparently pipeline already has all permissions needed to access other DevOps services.
Azure Function doesn't have it by default. And it looks pretty strange that Azure Function having its own system identity must use PAT for access to DevOps.
So it's actually my question (to MS mostly): 1) how can I provide access to DevOps services for system identity; 2) how can I get access token for Azure Function system identity.

Comment: You could pass through the system.accesstoken to the function so that the function can call out to REST APIs with the pipeline identity. You could also take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/NonInteractivePatGenerationSample. This example shows a way to request a user delegated (personal) access token for Azure DevOps. It requires you to authenticate against Azure Active Directory with username and password which should only be done in special circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [guidance document for various scenarios here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/et-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops)

But I believe that using a PAT (personal access token) will be simplest of the solutions as this is the only one that is listed as non interactive scenario. You could in theory also use a managed identity (service principal) if you can create role assignment for that service principal for devops API.